# Putting labels on top of buttons in an Android app

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-layout

I am trying to write a first `Android` app and I hit the following issue.

This is a loop handling some buttons:

```
   for (i in 0..7) {
        val btnID = resources.getIdentifier('N'.plus(i.toString()),"id",packageName)
        val imageBtn = findViewById<ImageButton>(btnID)
        imageBtn.setBackgroundColor(0x00)
        imageBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val result = Math.pow(2.toDouble(),i.toDouble()).toInt()
            val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2).apply {//
                text = result.toString()
            }
        }
        // Here I want to put a sticker: "Hi" on top of the button (imageBtn).
        .....
   }
```

The code above works, and the buttons behave as I expect.
Now I would like to stick a label on top of each button.
How can I do that? I have already tried tens of ways, following sample code I found on the net, but nothing works.

Below is a graphic to illustrate what I mean more precisely.

[image]

Of course "*Hi*" cannot be part of the button image because I need to change it dynamically. It can later become "*Ho*", "*He*", "*Pa*", ... or whatever according to the state of the app.

Comment: Why do you use a loop? Could give some details?

Comment: How do you want to visually place a label, can you share it as a picture?

Comment: I use a loop because there are several buttons(This is not really important for the question).
And I added a picture to the post to make it clear what I mean by having the label on top of the button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I had to spend some time and this may well be useful to someone else, I put here my solution. It now works exactly as I want.

Here it is:

```
   for (i in 0..7) {
        val btnID = resources.getIdentifier('N'.plus(i.toString()),"id",packageName)
        val imageBtn = findViewById<ImageButton>(btnID)
        imageBtn.setBackgroundColor(0x00)
        imageBtn.setOnClickListener {
            val result = Math.pow(2.toDouble(),i.toDouble()).toInt()
            val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2).apply {//
                text = result.toString()
            }
        }
        setSticker(i,btnID)
   }


    fun setSticker(n:Int,btn:Int) {
        val label = TextView(this)
        label.id = View.generateViewId()

        label.text = "Hi"
        label.setTextColor(Color.rgb(0xFF,0xFF,0xFF))
        label.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD)
        label.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, 17.dpToPixels(this))
        label.elevation = 0.dpToPixels(this) // To make the label visible (i.e. on top)

        constraintLayout?.addView(label)
        val constrSet = ConstraintSet()
        constrSet.clone(constraintLayout)
        constrSet.connect(label.id, ConstraintSet.LEFT, btn, ConstraintSet.LEFT)
        constrSet.connect(label.id, ConstraintSet.RIGHT, btn, ConstraintSet.RIGHT)
        constrSet.connect(label.id, ConstraintSet.TOP, btn, ConstraintSet.TOP)
        constrSet.connect(label.id, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM, btn, ConstraintSet.BOTTOM)
        constrSet.applyTo(constraintLayout)
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this might be work

```
 for (i in 0..7) {
        val btnID = resources.getIdentifier('N'.plus(i.toString()),"id",packageName)
        val imageBtn = findViewById<ImageButton>(btnID)
        imageBtn.setBackgroundColor(0x00)
        val result = Math.pow(2.toDouble(),i.toDouble()).toInt()
        imageBtn.setOnClickListener {
           
            val textView = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.textView2).apply {//
                text = result.toString()
            }
        }
        // Here I want to put a sticker: "Hi" on top of the button (imageBtn).
       imageBtn.text = result.toString()
   }
```

Comment: Thank you but unfortunately this does not work because imageBtn (ImageButton) has no text field.
I think I need a different component to hold the string "Hi".

Comment: Yes you can put button within relative or constraint layout and put text view in center of layout.

Comment: How can I do that ? I am writing my first Android app. There are many things I don't know in this world.

Answer (score 0):

Use this to your layout.

```
<RelativeLayout
       android:id="@+id/layoutButton"
       android:layout_width="60dp"
       android:layout_height="60dp">
    
       <ImageButton
           android:id="@+id/imgBtn"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:layout_height="match_parent" />
    
       <TextView
           android:layout_width="wrap_content"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content"
           android:text="Hi"
           android:layout_centerInParent="true"
           android:textSize="20sp" />
    
    
</RelativeLayout>
```

And Give `background` as per you want to `ImageButton`.

Comment: Can I use this dynamically to set the position of the "Hi" label on top of the button ?
I am now studying how ConstraintLayout and ConstraintSet work. I found this https://www.uwanttolearn.com/android/constraint-layout-animations-dynamic-constraints-ui-java-hell/ and made some progress. But I still do not exactly know how to place my label exactly on top of my button.

Answer (score 0):

For `Constraintlayout` Use this.

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:id="@+id/layoutButton"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp">

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/imgBtn"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Hi"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/imgBtn"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/imgBtn"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/imgBtn" />


    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use simlpe `Button` widget instead of `ImageButton`, it has `text` propertie. To make the button round just set simple shape drawable to the background.
For example, create drawable *circle.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="oval">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</shape>
```

And use it in the Button widget:

```
<Button
    ...
    android:background="@drawable/circle"
    .... />
```

Comment: Thanks. But I need an ImageButton, this is why I have this issue.
I finally found a solution.